# jQuery variable scope?

Tags: jquery

Why can’t I assign ajaxResult to result? console.log(result); works correctly which is inside the success option and appears second in the console. but result of the last of console.log(result); is undefined and first appears in the console. what is wrong with this?

```
$(function () {
        var result;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'GelinlikSet',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (ajaxResult) {
                result = ajaxResult;
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
        console.log(result);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

`result` should be set to `ajaxResult` *after* the `success` callback runs.

The AJAX callback won't be able to come back until the current thread is finished (i.e. the thread that is calling `$.ajax` and `console.log`).

If you need to perform some action with the result, you will have to do it from the `success` callback.

Answer (score 1):

The console.log outside the ajax call is being executed before the ajax returns.

The console.log in the success is where it should be to log something of the ajax.

Comment: just remove the last console.log, result's not meant to be defined there

Answer (score 0):

The second console.log is being executed immediately after the ajax call, before the success function gets called because it's Asynchronous (ie, The A in Ajax).